# Java EE dynamic web application development

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 classic and I need to do Java EE development.

How can I start development in eclipse 3.7 itself? A different version of Eclipse is available for Java EE development, but is it possible to use the 3.7 version itself?

From where can I get add-on plugins to do the Java EE development and web page creation?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by going to update sites for all the add-ons and plug-ins that you'd like.  The Eclipse for Java EE download is still 3.7 Indigo.  It just already has the typical suite of plugins for Java EE development installed.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2